# How to animate a fill color change on UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift

The shape is filled in correctly to begin with but I can't figure out how to change the fill color or, even better, how to animate a fill color change on a `UIBezierPath`. Just like changing the background color of a UIView is what I'm looking for.

```
var fillColor = UIColor()

func changeBackgroundColor() {

    let animcolor = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
    animcolor.fromValue = UIColor.greenColor()
    animcolor.toValue = UIColor.orangeColor()
    animcolor.duration = 1.0;
    animcolor.repeatCount = 0;
    animcolor.autoreverses = true
    shapeLayer.addAnimation(animcolor, forKey: "fillColor")

}


var fillColor = UIColor()
let clipPath = UIBezierPath()
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        clipPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 7.65, self.bounds.minY - 0.25))
        clipPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 7.65, self.bounds.minY + 36.1), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX - 2.38, self.bounds.minY + 9.79), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX - 2.38, self.bounds.minY + 26.06))
        clipPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 43.99, self.bounds.minY + 36.1), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 17.69, self.bounds.minY + 46.13), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 33.96, self.bounds.minY + 46.13))
        clipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 43.99, self.bounds.minY + 36.1))
        clipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 44.01, self.bounds.minY + 0.19))
        clipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 7.58, self.bounds.minY + 0.19))
        clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        fillColor = userColor
    }

clipPath.addClip()
fillColor.setFill()
clipPath.fill()
shapeLayer.path = clipPath.CGPath
self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just like changing the background color of a UIView is what I'm looking for.

But *why* can't you do exactly that? You're already masking the view to your path – so animating your background color would achieve the exact effect you want. Just get rid of the Core Graphics path filling – and also remove the `drawRect` override, as you [can't use `drawRect` with an animation of the background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902900/2976878).

If you *really* need to use `drawRect` and animate the color, you could consider splitting up your `UIView` into two `UIViews` - one to draw the background layer (which you could animate), and one to draw the custom drawing. Alternatively, you *could* setup a `CADisplayLink` to re-draw the view every frame with an intermediate background color – but that's not amazing in terms of performance.

As I say below, you can't animate the fill color of a `UIBezierPath` directly. If you only want to change (instead of animate) the fill color with your existing code, then you'd just want to call `setNeedsDisplay` with a different `userColor`.

If you're asking this because you're using two different paths for the masking and filling, see my below (overcomplicated in hindsight) answer.

---

The problem is the fill color of a `UIBezierPath` isn't animatable. But the fill color on a `CAShapeLayer` *is*.

Therefore you want to use another `CAShapeLayer` for the filling instead. I suggest you create a `fillLayer` and a `maskLayer` property in order to make their functions clear. Now because you're using a 100% layered approach, you can move your code out of the `drawRect`, as you're no longer doing any Core Graphics drawing.

Also, it's worth noting that you need to use a `CGColor` for the animation to and from values.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var fillColor = UIColor.greenColor()
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()

func changeBackgroundColor() {

    let animcolor = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
    animcolor.fromValue = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    animcolor.toValue = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
    animcolor.duration = 1.0;
    animcolor.repeatCount = 0;
    animcolor.autoreverses = true
    fillLayer.addAnimation(animcolor, forKey: "fillColor")

}

// re-adjust the clipping path when the view bounds changes
override func layoutSubviews() {

    let clipPath = UIBezierPath()
    clipPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 7.65, self.bounds.minY - 0.25))
    clipPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 7.65, self.bounds.minY + 36.1), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX - 2.38, self.bounds.minY + 9.79), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX - 2.38, self.bounds.minY + 26.06))
    clipPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 43.99, self.bounds.minY + 36.1), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 17.69, self.bounds.minY + 46.13), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 33.96, self.bounds.minY + 46.13))
    clipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 43.99, self.bounds.minY + 36.1))
    clipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 44.01, self.bounds.minY + 0.19))
    clipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.minX + 7.58, self.bounds.minY + 0.19))

    // update layer paths
    fillLayer.path = clipPath.CGPath
    maskLayer.path = clipPath.CGPath

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    // configure filling
    fillLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    // add fill path to superlayer
    layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)

    // configure masking layer
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you for working that into a better implementation. However I can not get the fill color of `fillLayer` to animate, I can't even get it to change. The function is definitely being called, I'm logging it to make sure. This is the kind of thing where I sit down and think I'll crank it out in 30-40 minutes and it ends up taking half the day.

Comment: @spacemonkey Is the `fillLayer` being displayed on-screen prior to animating? Make sure it's `frame` is non-zero, and it's added to the layer hierarchy. If you're using my above code, you'll need to initialise the `UIView` with the `init(frame:)` initialiser (in reality you'd want to move any size related code into a more suitable place, like `layoutSubviews` for instance).

Comment: Oh it's there. Exactly where, and the size, it should be. The fill color is set to what it should be as well, it just won't change to something else.

Comment: Hmm... weird. The code above is working fine for me in a test project. Did you make sure you added the `.CGColor` to the to and from values of the animation?

Comment: I know right, this is crazy. Even commented out the entire class and entered it verbatim.

Comment: @spacemonkey Dare I suggest cleaning your build folder and relaunching Xcode?

Comment: Yeah you totally nailed it. Of course I called it on the wrong instance. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version, you can check code in playground

```html
var fillColor = UIColor.green
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()

func changeBackgroundColor() {
    
    let animcolor = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
    animcolor.fromValue = UIColor.green.cgColor
    animcolor.toValue = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    animcolor.duration = 1.0;
    animcolor.repeatCount = 0;
    animcolor.autoreverses = true
    fillLayer.add(animcolor, forKey: "fillColor")
    
}

// re-adjust the clipping path when the view bounds changes

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

func createPaths() {
    let clipPath = UIBezierPath()
    clipPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 7.65, y: view.bounds.minY - 0.25))
    clipPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 7.65, y: view.bounds.minY + 36.1),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX - 2.38, y: view.bounds.minY + 9.79),
                      controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX - 2.38, y: view.bounds.minY + 26.06))
    clipPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 43.99, y: view.bounds.minY + 36.1),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 17.69, y: view.bounds.minY + 46.13),
                      controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 33.96, y: view.bounds.minY + 46.13))
    
    clipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 43.99, y: view.bounds.minY + 36.1))
    clipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 44.01, y: view.bounds.minY + 0.19))
    clipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.minX + 7.58, y: view.bounds.minY + 0.19))
    
    // update layer paths
    fillLayer.path = clipPath.cgPath
    maskLayer.path = clipPath.cgPath
    
    fillLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
    fillLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
    view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
    maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer
}

createPaths()
```