# Does animating the fill color of a `UIBezierPath` require a new scan-convert?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

Consider a chess game. A self-contained `ViewController` and a `ChessPieceView` appear below. (On my Xcode 10, Playgrounds do not support graphics, hence the use of a full-fledged, if minuscule, project.)

We animate the motion of the chess piece. We would also like to animate the color of a circle surrounding it (for chess tutorials and such).

Here we animate `View.backgroundColor`. But what we would really like to do is to animate the fill color of the circle. The `backgroundColor` of the piece will be the fill color of the from/to squares, whatever these are.

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100),
                          size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        let chessPieceView = ChessPieceView.init(fromFrame: rect)
        self.view.addSubview(chessPieceView)
    }
}


//  ChessPieceView.swift
import UIKit
class ChessPieceView: UIView {
    init(fromFrame frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let circle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY),
                                  radius: 30,
                                  startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2,
                                  clockwise: false)
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        circle.fill()
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                    action: #selector(tapPiece(_ :))))
    }
    @objc func tapPiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer ) {
        guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else { return }
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1.2,
                                                  curve: .easeInOut,
                                                  animations: {
                                                    self.center.x += 100
                                                    self.center.y += 200
            })
            animator.startAnimation()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2) {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The difficulty appears that one ["can't animate the fill color of a UIBezierPath directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36535035/700648). That is because, it seems, iOS does not re-render (aka re-scan-convert) the path at all. When an animation is requested, a (relatively cheap) composition operation is performed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `layoutSubviews()` is absolutely ***NOT*** the place to put `addGestureRecognizer()` ... that should be done during initialization.

Second, you'll probably have much better results by using a `CAShapeLayer` instead of overriding `draw()`.

Give this a try:

```
class ChessPieceView: UIView {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    init(fromFrame frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                    action: #selector(tapPiece(_ :))))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let r: CGFloat = 30
        let rect = CGRect(x: bounds.midX - r, y: bounds.midY - r, width: r * 2, height: r * 2)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath
    }
    @objc func tapPiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer ) {
        guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else { return }
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1.2,
                                                  curve: .easeInOut,
                                                  animations: {
                                                    self.center.x += 100
                                                    self.center.y += 200
                                                    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                                                  })
            animator.startAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Re-reading your question, it looks like you want to animate the fill-color of the circle.

In that case, you can use the shape layer as a mask. This class will draw a red-filled circle... tapping it will animate its position and animate the red-to-yellow color change:

```
class ChessPieceView: UIView {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    init(fromFrame frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                    action: #selector(tapPiece(_ :))))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let r: CGFloat = 30
        let rect = CGRect(x: bounds.midX - r, y: bounds.midY - r, width: r * 2, height: r * 2)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath
        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
    @objc func tapPiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer ) {
        guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else { return }
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1.2,
                                                  curve: .easeInOut,
                                                  animations: {
                                                    self.center.x += 100
                                                    self.center.y += 200
                                                    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                                                  })
            animator.startAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

This example uses a subview to provide a cyan rectangle with a round red view in the center... each tap will animate the position of the rectangle, and the color of the circle in its center:

```
class ChessViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100),
                          size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        let chessPieceView = ChessPieceView.init(fromFrame: rect)
        self.view.addSubview(chessPieceView)
    }
}


//  ChessPieceView.swift

class ChessPieceView: UIView {
    let circleView = UIView()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var startCenter: CGPoint!
    
    init(fromFrame frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        startCenter = self.center
        backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        addSubview(circleView)
        circleView.backgroundColor = .red
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                    action: #selector(tapPiece(_ :))))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let r: CGFloat = 30
        circleView.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.midX - r, y: bounds.midY - r, width: r * 2, height: r * 2)
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = r
    }
    @objc func tapPiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer ) {
        guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else { return }
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            let targetCenter: CGPoint = self.center.x == startCenter.x ? CGPoint(x: startCenter.x + 100, y: startCenter.y + 200) : startCenter
            let targetColor: UIColor = self.circleView.backgroundColor == .red ? .yellow : .red
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1.2,
                                                  curve: .easeInOut,
                                                  animations: {
                                                    self.center = targetCenter
                                                    self.circleView.backgroundColor = targetColor
                                                  })
            animator.startAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: All good, but the `self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow` at the end of your code is executed immediately (which we know to expect), but it also takes place immediately. The `backgroundColor` does not fade from the old to the new values during the animation.

Comment: @Sam - maybe I'm not completely understanding your goal? There are various ways to animate positions and color changes (along with other properties)... I put up another approach, using a subview for the center "circle". See **Edit 2** in my answer (including a capture of it in action).

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the manually rendered `UIBezierPath` is not directly animatable.

You have two options:

1. Instead of a view with a custom `draw(_:)` that strokes/fills a path, instead add a `CAShapeLayer` and set its `path`. The `fillColor` of that shape layer is animatable (via `CABasicAnimation`).
2. If you want to animate a view with a manual `draw(_:)` implementation (or animate any non-animatable property), you can call [`transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition). It basically takes a snapshot of the “before” view, and animates the transition from that snapshot to the new rendition.

Generally we would use the `CAShapeLayer` approach, but I provide both options for your reference.